# Column Guides Are Unlocked But I Still Can't Move Columns In A Text Frame

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud

I'm using Adobe InDesign CC. I have a three column text frame and I need the middle frame to be just a bit larger than the left and right columns. I have unlocked Column Guides by unchecking `View > Grids & Guides > Unlock Column Guides`, but with both the `Selection Tool` and `Direct Selection Tool` I don't get the cursor changing nor does clicking and dragging on the guide do anything but move the entire text frame.

I have read tutorials with pictures and I see that it's possible, however I must be missing something. Help!

EDIT: This is a blue text frame I'm talking about, not the purple column guides that would be established in the document settings.

[image: Screenshot of column guides]

Comment: Those appear to he text frame guides for columns. Not the same as page column guides.

Comment: Probably, you should unlock the layer, my friend!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't alter the width of an individual column within a text frame, they all have to be equal. To create columns of unequal width or height, create threaded text frames (a story) side-by-side on either a document page or a master page.

Comment: Oh. That's too bad - it seems to me it would be a lot faster to just click and drag.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's unchecked on right click as well:
[image]

*That  being said, typography wise you never want to do that - it's better to separate the column grid into smaller groups, for example in your case separate it into 7 columns so you have 2-2-3, or 4 columns so you have 2-1-1, or something like that*

Comment: It's also unchecked on right click. The guides and gutter are light blue, not purple - they are part of a text frame. Is this somehow different?

Comment: yea, that's a text box! (unless you changed the default guide colours). Check that you don't have any element locked (Object>Unlock all on spread)

Comment: either that or a regular guide - is lock guides checked?

Comment: `Lock Guides` is also unchecked. I did not change the default guide colours, but I'll post a screen clip of the box in question.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Thanks for the help - looks like I was trying to alter text-frame column guides, not "column guides" in the regular sense. Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score -1):

Check your A-master?  Double click and delete/move from there